# Is there a way to map IP blocks to a given location (e.g. lat/long + radius)?

Tags: geolocation, ip-geolocation

Is there a way to map IP blocks to a given location (e.g. lat/long + radius)?

"Normal" geoIP lookups give you an location (address/city/region/country) from an IP address.

Have any geoIP databases been "inverted" to allow the opposite, i.e. provide a geographic location  (e.g. a polygon whose vertices are lat/long pairs, or a circle centered on a lat/long) and get a list of likely IP address blocks that might reasonably be associated with it?

The simplest version of this is something like this:  https://lite.ip2location.com/ip-address-ranges-by-country?lang=en_US, which provides a static list (I assume) of the IP blocks associated with a country.

All search results assume I'm looking for a geoIP lookup function, e.g. https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-demo?ip_address=1.2.3.4

Given that geoIP databases exist, this seems as though it might be reducible to a query/queries (increasingly more specific given a top-level address block), but none of the geoIP libraries I've used provide that capability.